# proof - set of remainders of a prime p multiplied by another co prime

Tags: math, primes, proof

I've solvde the problem nuggets on usaco. I came to a point that I needed to prove that:

If we have a set `S` that contain numbers `(0,1,2,3,...P-1)` where `P` is a prime number. If we multiplied this set `* X [where X and P are co-primes (relative primes)]` we will get the same set `S`, maybe with different arrangement, but we will get the same elements. After multiplication we will take `mod P` for each element in the set.

Is that any theorem, or can it be proof related to this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You multiply set by X and claim it's unchanged which is untrue obviously... Please clarify.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake .. I forgot to say that after multiplication we will take mod P for each element in the set - now updated with an example

Comment: For future reference, this question makes a lot more sense on math.stackexchange

Comment: This question belongs on math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose, there are `i` and `j` in `(0,1,2,3,...P-1)` which yield same value for `lambda a: (a*x)%p`.

then

```
i*x = j*x mod p
=> i*x - j*x = 0 mod p
=> (i - j)*x = 0 mod p
```

so `p` divides `(i-j)*x`. now `p` and `x` are co prime, so `p` does not divide `x`. So `p | i - j`

Now notice, `i` and `j` both are less than `p`. so `i - j` also less than `p`. So `p` can not divide `i - j` unless, it is `zero`. So `i - j = 0` `=> i = j`.

So if `i` and `j` yields same, `i = j`. So when `i != j`, `i` and `j` yield different integers. So for each `i` in `(0,1,2,3,...P-1)`, `lambda a: (a*x)%p` yields different integer. So if you collect the integer in a set, the set must have `p` elements. But all the integers must be less than `p`. So the set contains each elements from `(0,1,2,...P-1)`.

---

Remark : `p` does not necessarily need to be prime. All it takes, `p` and `x` to be co prime.

Comment: about your Remark ... You said `Now notice, i and j both are less than p. so i - j also less than p. So p can not divide i - j unless, it is zero.` 
doesn't that mean that `p` HAS TO be prime? because if not .. `p` may divide `i-j` ?

Comment: @Merna no, it is not i - j divides p, it is if p divides i - j. If a | b, then a <= b. so p | i - j implies p <= i - j. but i - j < p ! So contradiction !